# Confluent S3 Sink Connector for Kafka unable to connect to S3 using MSK / MSK Connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-kafka, aws-msk, aws-msk-connect

I'm attempting to store my Kafka messages to S3 using Apache MSK / MSK Connect and the Confluent S3 Sink Connector.

I'm experiencing a timeout error when the connector tries to reach S3.

To rule out a permissions issue, I've given the connector role full access to S3, but that hasn't resolved the issue.

The configuration I'm using is as follows:

```
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector
format.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.format.json.JsonFormat
flush.size=3
tasks.max=1
name=kafka-connect-s3
storage.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage
topics.regex=.*
s3.bucket.name=######-kafka-messages
```

```
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  (io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.PartitionerConfig:361)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0] [2022-04-12 13:52:24,646] INFO [kafka-connect-s3|task-0] Returning new credentials provider based on the configured credentials provider class (io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage:186)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0] [2022-04-12 13:53:05,352] ERROR [kafka-connect-s3|task-0] WorkerSinkTask{id=kafka-connect-s3-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:191)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0] org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com:443 [s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/52.95.131.12] failed: connect timed out
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkTask.start(S3SinkTask.java:138)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.initializeAndStart(WorkerSinkTask.java:308)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:196)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:189)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:238)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0] Caused by: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com:443 [s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/52.95.131.12] failed: connect timed out
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1207)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1153)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:802)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:704)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:550)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:530)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5445)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5392)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getAcl(AmazonS3Client.java:4050)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getBucketAcl(AmazonS3Client.java:1273)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getBucketAcl(AmazonS3Client.java:1263)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.doesBucketExistV2(AmazonS3Client.java:1401)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage.bucketExists(S3Storage.java:197)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkTask.start(S3SinkTask.java:112)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  ... 9 more
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0] Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com:443 [s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/52.95.131.12] failed: connect timed out
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:151)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionManagerFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionManagerFactory.java:76)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy47.connect(Unknown Source)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1331)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1145)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  ... 24 more
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0] Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:368)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory.connectSocket(SdkTLSSocketFactory.java:142)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0]  ... 40 more
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0] [2022-04-12 13:53:05,354] INFO [kafka-connect-s3|task-0] Metrics scheduler closed (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics:668)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0] [2022-04-12 13:53:05,354] INFO [kafka-connect-s3|task-0] Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics:672)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0] [2022-04-12 13:53:05,354] INFO [kafka-connect-s3|task-0] Metrics reporters closed (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics:678)
[Worker-0bfbcc480ad565df0] [2022-04-12 13:53:05,355] INFO [kafka-connect-s3|task-0] App info kafka.consumer for connector-consumer-kafka-connect-s3-0 unregistered (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:83)
```

What could be going wrong? The subnets can access the Internet and have an Internet Gateway attached. The Network ACLs are the default settings.

Comment: 1) AWS support can help you better 2) Is ap-southeast-2 the correct region where your bucket  exists?

Comment: My understanding is that S3 is global? I've tried it with both `ap-southeast-2` and `us-west-2`, which is global. I do have an open ticket with AWS, but it's a bit of a slow process.

Comment: S3 is not global, no. Buckets exist in specific regions, and by default the MSK Connect will attempt to write to the same region it is deployed to

Comment: Regarding the exception, either the VPC or firewall is blocking outbound traffic on port 443 or is otherwise denying S3 access, or the S3 API is actually down in that region. There's nothing wrong with your connector config

Comment: In this case, the security group is allowing all traffic (IPv4 All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0) and there are no firewall rules that I've set up.

Comment: I assume that is an inbound rule? By default, security groups allow all outbound traffic.

Comment: Is your msk cluster publicly available? If this is the case maybe you have to do the workaround mentioned here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/msk-connect-internet-access.html

Comment: Did you find a solution to this. We are running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an endpoint for S3 as described in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/mkc-tutorial-setup.html). Then check a secutiry group you assigned to the connector has permission to go outside. For example, you can set an outbound rule: "All trafic/All protocols/All ports" > 0.0.0.0/0